# How can a runtime object type be used as a generic type hint parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

## Introduction

With Python/MyPy type hints, one can use .pyi stubs to keep annotations in separate files to implementations. I am using this functionality to give basic hinting of SQLAlchemy's ORM (more specifically, the `flask_sqlalchemy` plugin).

Models are defined like:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column()
    ...
...
```

where `db.Model` is included directly from SQLAlchemy.
They can be queried, for example, by:

```
MyModel.query.filter({options: options}).one_or_none()
```

where `filter()` returns another `Query`, and `one_or_none()` returns an instance of `MyModel` (or `None`,  obviously).

The follwing .pyi file successfully hints the above construct, though it is incomplete - there is no way to hint the return type of `one_or_none()`.

```
class _SQLAlchemy(sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session):
    class Model:
       query = ... # type: _Query

class _Query(sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query):
    def filter(self, *args) -> query.Query: ...
    def one_or_none(self) -> Any: ...

db = ... # type: _SQLAlchemy
```

## The Question

How can one fully and generically hint the above, and hint the return type of `one_or_none()`?
My first attempt was to use generics, but it looks like I have no access to the the subtype in question (in the given example, `MyModel`). To illustrate a nonworking approach:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')

class _SQLAlchemy(sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session):
    class Model:
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           self.query = ... # type: _Query[self.__class__]

class _Query(Generic[_T], sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query):
    def filter(self, *args) -> _Query[_T]: ...
    def one_or_none(self) -> _T: ...

db = ... # type: _SQLAlchemy
```

Is there any way to get this working?

Apologies for the specific and example, but I tried for a while to write this concisely with a generic example and it was never as clear as it is currently (which is possibly still not much!)

### Edit

Another non-working approach (I'm aware this would have the limitation of having to call `myModelInstance.query`... instead of the static `MyModel.query`, but even this does not work):

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')

class _SQLAlchemy(sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session):
    class Model:

       @property
       def query(self: _T) -> _Query[_T]: ...

class _Query(Generic[_T], sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query):
    def filter(self, *args) -> _Query[_T]: ...
    def one_or_none(self) -> _T: ...

db = ... # type: _SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 2):

Type annotation stubs are fortunately now available for that specific issue https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs

Exact implementation for `Query` type annotation is available here: https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs/blob/master/sqlalchemy-stubs/orm/query.pyi ([archive](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs/blob/280d810a854794c1ab9d845b75e4643d0c89e094/sqlalchemy-stubs/orm/query.pyi))